# How do i create a online forum?

Tags: php, mysql

Is there any way that i can create my own forum using php and mysql knowledge?The forum should be able to

1. show points for answered questions
2. be able to support question and answering
3. also be able to create a small news feed 
   I wanna learn this process from scratch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to Stack Overflow!

If you're familiar with Laravel, then I suggest giving ["Let's Build A Forum With Laravel" on Laracasts](https://laracasts.com/series/lets-build-a-forum-with-laravel) a shot.

Very insightful tutorial-series on making a forum from scratch.